# How to make hard disk space virtually unlimited?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid

We work with video editing. We produce about 30TB of raw footage every year and we are getting crazy. In fact, we keep buying hard drives and putting new projects into different hard drives every time.

The problem is, having now 14 4TB Hard Drives, we keep forgetting everyday where each project is and we have problems each time we re-open an old project because when you change files paths, the editing software has to re-link all media.

So, we thought: isn't it possible to virtually transform all the hard drives we have into a single hard drive? And, also, to expand such storage every time we want by adding new phisycal drives to it? **Our goal is to get a virtually infinite hard disk space**

Raid 0 is an option, but the more hard disks you add, the higher chance to loose all data you have.

We were wondering whether there are some safe alternatives to Raid 0, or some other solutions that can let you "see" one single storage unit and expand it as you want.

Comment: [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them) article should cover most, if not all, questions about RAID.

Comment: RAID 6 allows for both the speed and for HDDs to fail.  RAID isn't a backup solution though

Comment: I would use dynamic disks. ==> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Question is overly broad. You could build a large array yourself, RAID6 as above, or buy an off the shelf SAN unit, or buy the likes of Synology or QNAP and every time you fill 8 bays add another 8 bays to the "cluster". Have a look what Linus Tech Tips do, will give you ideas.

Comment: ZFS is what you are looking for.

Comment: There are too many “LVM-ish” solutions available. You need to narrow down your question to get proper answers – there is not a single business requirement in your question. What OS? What hardware? How do you access it? Why don’t you archive old projects on tape?

Comment: @Iain ZFS is great for many reasons, but without redundancy, it suffers from the exact same problem as any other RAID 0 solution: if one disk dies, your data is more or less guaranteed to go to The Great Bitbucket in the Sky. After you pass the redundancy threshold, it's also difficult (much more so than most other file systems) to repair the damage.

Comment: ZFS doesn't work like that.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I don't think anyone is suggesting unRAIDed ZFS.

Comment: @ewwhite Let's hope not, but the original comment with the suggestion just said ZFS. (Iain, don't get me wrong; I use ZFS myself. It's just very easy to fall into traps that are hard, or sometimes practically impossible, to get yourself out of without rebuilding your storage from scratch.)

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would think of using ZFS in a non RAID config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several software solutions that will create a striped raid that will allow for a percentage of disks to fail without loosing data (unlike raid 0)

See

- [freenas](http://www.freenas.org/)
- [unraid](http://lime-technology.com/)
- [lvm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux))

You can alternatively invest in a hardware solution that will do the same thing. Consider:

- [synology](https://www.synology.com/en-us/)
- [drobo](http://www.drobo.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest speaking to a storage vendor who specializes in scalable storage solutions. They can give you ideas and actually craft a solution based on real requirements. I like [Pogo Storage](http://www.pogostorage.com).

This can clearly be handled with a SAN or something that presents NAS shares, but a well-architected ZFS solution is also an option.

I'm assuming there's not much of a budget, but if you're looking for real scale-out NAS, something like EMC Isilon is still relevant in this industry.

*How much is your data worth?*

[**Whatever you do, don't be this guy!!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSrnXgAmK8k)

[image]